# Salesforce ListView Deployment Error

Tags: deployment, list-view

How to solve 'Invalid scope:mine' Deployment Error While Deploying Salesforce ListView Filter (ownerbased) using VS Code.

Comment: Please deploy your listviews with **"Everything"** in filterscope and then change it to **"Mine"** through the UI. - https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000qQ8ldAAC/invalid-scopemine-error-when-deploying-listview-with-metadata-api

Comment: This kind of deployment comes when you try to deploy Listview FIlter so you have to add filter manual in QA/production this will not deploy using VS Code/Metadata api.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [Known Issue](https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000qQ8ldAAC/invalid-scopemine-error-when-deploying-listview-with-metadata-api), and has not been fixed.

There is a workaround in [this article](https://nicolas.vuillamy.fr/invalid-scope-mine-not-allowed-deploy-your-listviews-anyway-443aceca8ac7) if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of deployment comes when you try to deploy Listview FIlter so you have to add filter manual in QA/production this will not deploy using VS Code/Metadata api.